# Angular6 HttpClient catchError not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

CatchError is completelly ignored in 401 response.

I have httpInterceptor that handles oauth2 authentication.

Relevant code is :

```
import { filter, take, switchMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
//ommited
if (authService.hasRefreshToken()) {
    return authService.doRefreshToken().pipe(switchMap(tokenResponse => {
            const accessToken = tokenResponse['access_token'];
            this.tokenSubject.next(accessToken);
            return <Observable<HttpEvent<any>>> next.handle(this.addToken(req, accessToken));
        }), catchError((err: any, caught: any) => {
            console.log(err)
            return Observable.throw(err);
        })
    )
}
```

AuthService class:

```
export class AuthService {
    doRefreshToken() {
        //ommited
        return this.httpClient.post(environment.baseUrl + this.tokenEndpoint, null, requestOptions).pipe(
            map(tokenResponse => {
                this.saveToken(tokenResponse);
                return tokenResponse;
            }),
            catchError((err: any, caught: Observable<Object>) => {
                //refreshing token failed (refrech token invalid or expired) redirect to login and wipe everything
                this.logout();
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }));
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for 200 response, but 401 error is completely ignored.
Am i using this new catchError the wrong way ?

P.S. this piece of code was working just fine with plain old catch , but now when i migrated to angular6 pipe and catchError same stuff just doesnt work.

EDIT :

Breakpoint on catchError reveals

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at AuthService.push../src/app/common/auth/auth.service.ts.AuthService.doRefreshToken

Actual response from the server is :

```
{
 "error" : "invalid_token",
 "error_description" : "Refresh token expired"
}
```

Headers :

```
 Request Method: POST
 Status Code: 401
```

Comment: does doRefreshToken() work well ?

Comment: breakpoint on catchError in doRefreshToken() shows Unexpected end of input at message. This method does indeed work well when response is 200 and token renewal is successful.

Comment: @SeaBiscuit did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue with a 400 response not making it to the catchError...

Comment: Not really. It just stopped working after i upgraded to angular 6. Luckily we are still in development so I pushed this issue to the end of the backlog and hoped someone would post something here :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue of the `catchError` function being completely ignored. Since this simple and straightforward code used by @SeaBiscuit as described in the official [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) did not work, I abandoned that approach to handling error responses and instead looked at HttpInterceptors. And that worked!

I was inspired by the guidance of Luuk Gruijs in his article [Global HTTP error catching in Angular 4.3+](https://hackernoon.com/global-http-error-catching-in-angular-4-3-9e15cc1e0a6b) to add the `ErrorInterceptor` shown below to my code.

Admittedly, the interceptor below may not be a perfect, but the most important part for handling errors in interceptors boils down to this:

```
next.handle(request).pipe(tap(
  (event: HttpEvent<any>) => { },
  (error: any) => {
    // Handle errors here!
  }
))
```

---

Here's a more detailed glimpse at what I implemented:

```
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept (request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.method !== 'GET') {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    const subject = new AsyncSubject<HttpEvent<any>>();

    next.handle(request)
    .pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        // Let HttpResponses pass through interceptor without interaction
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          subject.next(event);
          subject.complete();
        }
      }, (error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          const errorEvent = new HttpResponse({
            body: {
              message: error.error.message,
              status: error.status,
              statusText: error.statusText
            }
          });

          subject.next(errorEvent);
          subject.complete();
        }
      })
    ).subscribe();

    return subject;
  }
}
```

I also modified my service to accept that manually created response body:

```
return this.http.get<MyObjI | ErrorI>(url, {params});
```

... where `ErrorI` is:

```
export interface ErrorI {
  message: string;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
}
```

Hopefully handling errors in an interceptor does the trick for you, too!

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.throw()` **cannot be use in a return statement**.

[> Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits an error notification.](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw)

that is why you are getting the syntax error on `AuthService.doRefreshToken`

`Observable.throw()` throws an error that is why you are not allowed to use it in a `return` statement.

It is the same thing as the following,

```
return throw Error("")
```

You can easily get complaining from your ESlint.

**Anyway, since this is a old question, you'd should be using the new API but I hope this can help users from the old rxjs API.**